# Nativescript issue with RadsideDrawer on iOS

Tags: ios, camera, nativescript-angular, nativescript-camera

I'm facing an issue on iOS. My app supports attachments, including from camera. We are using @nativescript/camera for that. However every time I open the camera and return from it (after taking a picture or I cancel), the bottom navigation of the app becomes transparent and loses its height. i.e. the content above it takes up the full height of the screen. I'm using RadSideDrawer, as there's also a side panel.
My screen is structured as follows:

```
<RadSideDrawer>
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent>
        <StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <GridLayout tkMainContent>
    <loading-screen></loading-screen>
        <GridLayout rows="*, auto">
          <StackLayout row="0">
                <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
          </StackLayout>
          <nav-bar *ngIf="showNavBar$ | async" row="1"></nav-bar>
        </GridLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

Has anyone seen this before or know of any way to work around it ? This only happens on iOS, Android is cooperating fine.

Tried fitting tkMainContent into an extra StackLayout, giving it fixed height etc, this still happened consistently. I can see tkMainContent reloading when I'm coming back into the app.
Also tried giving fixed heights to grid rows.
Added a timeout on the attach event in the camera, but the reload (and resize) seems to be happening before that) and suspend and resume aren't triggered at all in this case, when I'm using the camera.